# How to mock a component with different return for each test block

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to mock my component and to have a different return for each "it/test" block, something like this:

```js
it('should render component', () => {
  jest.mock("../MyComponent", () => {
    return () =>
      <div>
        My mocked component
      </div>
  })
  
  //...
});

it('should render component with input', () => {
  jest.mock("../MyComponent", () => {
    return () => 
      <div>
        Now my component has an input
        <input type="text" />
      </div>
  })

  //...
});
```

I searched in the docs, but I was not able to find some example of this. To solve this problem I created another test file that calls the same component but with a different mock

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a bit more context about what is it that you are trying to test? There might be a different way to achieve that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `jest.mock()` API can do this. After mocking the component module, you should import the component(now it has been mocked) and call `.mockImplementation()` API to provide different mock implementations for your component.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return <div>MyComponent</div>;
};

export default MyComponent;
```

`App.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

export const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyComponent />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`App.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { App } from './App';
import MyComponent from './MyComponent';

jest.mock('./MyComponent');

const MyComponentMock = MyComponent as jest.MockedFunction<typeof MyComponent>;

describe('75113485', () => {
  test('should pass - 1', () => {
    MyComponentMock.mockImplementation(() => {
      return <div>My mocked component</div>;
    });
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText('My mocked component')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });

  test('should pass - 2', () => {
    MyComponentMock.mockImplementation(() => {
      return (
        <div>
          Now my component has an input
          <input type="text" />
        </div>
      );
    });
    render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByRole('textbox')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/75113485/App.test.tsx (9.248 s)
  75113485
    ✓ should pass - 1 (28 ms)
    ✓ should pass - 2 (49 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.721 s
```